# Hitbodedut- Permissable? Reccomended?

Tags: tefilla, breslov

What are the main opinions regarding hitbodedut? I strongly recall being taught we're not supposed to bother Hashem more than three times a day, though I can't find an actual prohibition anywhere.

Comment: Hi Josh. Probably the main opinions are it's great and it's a waste of time. Is that really all you want to know? I recommend editing your question to clarify what exactly you want to find out. The clearer you are, the better we can help you.

Comment: `we're not supposed to bother Hashem more than three times a day` This sounds very strange to me. ולואי שיתפלל אדם כל היום כולו "if only a person would pray all day" ([Brachot 21a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=21&format=text); the argument is only about repeating Shmone Esre). ומי כה' אלהינו בכל קראנו אליו "who is like our God whenever we call out to him"

Comment: Is your question about hisbodedut or about prayer?

Comment: "bother Hashem" what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: @Heshy- the same way we avoid unnecessarily saying a brecha....if you have a better term to employ than "bothering", I'm all ears!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is ample evidence that Gedolei Yisroel "bothered" Hashem more than three times a day. First, there is the Gemara Berachos 28b and 54a (Mishna 9:1) that teaches we should say a tefila at every juncture of uncertainty throughout the day. Then there is the mitzvah to say 100 berachos per day. And on and on. Regarding hisbodedus specifically, the Mishna Berura mentions it in passing in 111:2 as something that appears completely permissible.