# Is hitbodedut considered a mitzvah?

Tags: tefilla, mitzvah

Do personal prayers to Hashem (hitbodedut) fulfill a mitzvah? It would be a great incentive for me to pray more.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe this is separate from the general mitzvah of prayer?

Comment: See also the answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88856/hitbodedut-permissable-reccomended

Comment: That post does not explain whether it's a mitzvah or not

Comment: Another aspect of hitbodedut specifically, in contrast to hitbonenut, is that it is somewhat related to the mitzvah of maintaining proper health, physically, mentally and emotionally (think Mishneh Torah, Hilchot De'ot, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Siman 32 and elsewhere).